# Accessibility setting change value on Shared Preferences

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have an App which have behavior like a KIOS. There is an Activity will show to user and user cannot back or close it because it's need a password.

There is one case if the owner of App forgot the password. So I need to implement external setting (like IOS) outside the App to change value on my Shared Preferences to close the Activity KIOS.

I read some articles and the close way is using Accessibility but the information and example about this is so difficult to find. So I still learn and testing about it.

Here what I've done:

SettingProgram.java

```
public class SettingProgram extends AccessibilityService {
    public static boolean isGuestMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
//            isGuestMode = false;


    /*I want to 
      if switch the Accessibility turn on the boolean isGuestMode become true, 
      and if it turn off the isGuestMode become false
     */
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() { }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
    }
}
```

accessibility_services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" 
    android:settingsActivity="com.mobile.Testing.SettingProgram"/>
```

I have read:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this with `Accessibility Service` to call another layout. Here the way :

• I create accessibility xml file as documentation say like below :

```
<accessibility-service
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
   android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
   android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
   android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
   android:settingsActivity="com.mobile.vhp.checkin.SettingAndList.GeneralSetting"/>
```

From that, I have Accessibility Service for my App in Setting which have and Option Menu name `Guest Mode`. The guest mode will call General Setting Activity to set another setting for my Apps outside the App.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that AccessibilityService is what you need. Because doc's says:

> An Accessibility Service assists users with disabilities in using
>   Android devices and apps. It is a long-running privileged service that
>   helps users process information on the screen and lets them to
>   interact meaningfully with a device.

I can suggest you to use remote call like Firebase Push message, when program receives some special message it will change password or remove etc.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I don't use Firebase and I have own service. I have post my answer below. Thank You